# ko.computed tracking changes of the elements of an array

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to create a ko.computed field notified of changes happening to the elements of an array?

My first thought was to use observableArray, but it did not work, because

> [An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the
>   state of those objects](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Still, I'm posting this piece of code to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:arr">
    <input type="text" value="" data-bind="value: a" />
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach:arr">
    <p>
        Field "a" is changed: <span data-bind="text: aChanged()? 'true': 'false'"></span>
    </p>   
</div>
<p>
    Some "a" field from the array is changed: <span data-bind="text: someAChanged()? 'true': 'false'"></span>
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.arr = ko.observableArray([new A(), new A()]);
    this.someAChanged = ko.computed(function () {
        var ch = false;
        var arr = this.arr();
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
            if (arr[i].aChanged()) {
                ch = true;
                break;
            }
            return ch;
        }
    }, this);    
}

function A() {
    this.a = ko.observable(1);
    this.aChanged = ko.computed(function() { 
        return this.a() != 1;
    }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

As I have no rights to answer my own questions, I'm posting my idea here.
I decided to use "subscribe" function. My solution is to add a "parent" link to the elements of an array. Whenever an observable field gets changed a parent field dependent on its children gets changed too:

```
function Child () {
    this._parent = null;
    this.observableField = ko.observable("");
    this.observableField.subscribe(function (newVal) {
         if (newVal... && this._parent) {
             this._parent.anotherObservableField(...);
         }
    });
}
Child.prototype._setParent(parent) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make sure that the `someAChanged` computed is registering a dependency on each item in your array.

Something like this should work:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.arr = ko.observableArray([new A(), new A()]);
    this.someAChanged = ko.computed(function () {
        var ch = false;
        var changedItem = null;
        var arr = this.arr();

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.arr(), function(item){
            var changed = item.changed(); //someAChanged registers a change subscription here

            if(changed && !ch){
                ch = true;
                changedItem = item;
            }
        });

        return changedItem;
    }, this);    
};
```

Essentially this registers a "change" subscription for each item in your array. Your previous code was stopping at the first one it found, which means none of the other items in your array had "change" subscriptions added. Looping through each item in your array and making it a dependency of your `someAChanged` computed *could* be expensive if you have a lot of items in your array.

The code above will also return the first item that changed. I assumed this is what you were wanting. If not, it would be pretty easy to re-work it to return an array of changed items.

Comment: [Navneet Gupta](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3846772/navneet-gupta) posted this: "How does it work if new items are added into the observableArray? How do they are subscribed to?"

Comment: @PeterO shouldn't be a problem, as the computed invokes `this.arr()`, so it registers to the array as well, then in the `ko.utils.arrayForEach` call, will subscribe to `changed` prop of the newly added item.

Answer (score 0):

I did it setting a simple initial values on create and check for any of the field i want to checkout if are changed on a computed observable like this:

```
    var initPrice = line.Price;
    var initCurrency = line.IdCurrency;

    self.isModified = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.Price() !== initPrice || self.IdCurrency() !== initCurrency;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there I think. Your html is fine as is your knockout, but your someAChanged computed function wasn't functioning properly.  If an A had changed you were setting the ch variable to true and breaking out of the for loop but you never actually returned true.  In actuality you don't need the ch variable at all.

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.arr = ko.observableArray([new A(), new A()]);
    this.someAChanged = ko.computed(function () {
        var arr = this.arr();
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
            if (arr[i]().aChanged()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }, this);  
}
```